# How to jump to the last code snippet in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debug

We can go to the declaring code snippet by click **Open Declaration** menu(F3).

But how to go back where I jump here?

For example we jump from file **A** line **39** to file **B** line **10**,how to switch back?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ALT+Left arrow` shortcut, which brings you to previous editor location.